# flask-dance: Edit `scopes` grants depending on changes in user behavior/choices

Tags: flask, flask-dance

I am using [flask-dance](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance) to build a simple OAuth app. There is a use case where I start with a minimal set of OAuth scope grant to the user  (on Github), but depending on chosen actions, additional scopes can be granted. This seems to be a common use case but am not able to find a way to do this in `flask-dance` (that is trigger the re-authorization workflow for github).

Has any used `flask-dance` to address this use case?

I tried editing the scopes `blueprint_demo.scopes=[..scopes..]` but that did not trigeer any re authorization flow.